# Can the usage of the UI Document (form the UI Toolkit) without a camera be considered a good practice in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, conventions, ui-toolkit

I'm need a low resolution (pixelated) view for my game and am using a render texture, so the camera isn't rendering anything to the screen/game view. To bring the downscaled view to the player I'm using UI Document with a basic UI Element that has the mentioned earlier render texture as a background.

It works just fine, no error occur, besides the message "No camera rendering" in the Editor, so no errors in the build.

[image]

But I'm not quite sure if it is a good way to do. Also with the UI Toolkit I don't need a camera for the main menu.

So, is it a good practice not to use a camera in a scene if I have only the new UI (without Canvas)?

Comment: Whether it's good or not is in your judgement, but AFAIK uGUI is still the recommended runtime UI system, so it's a bit earlier to try UI Toolkit at this moment.

Comment: @shingo I wouldn't claim the latter .. you can try out things as soon as they are in alpha state ;) UI toolkit has some huge advantages regarding the whole CSS styles being easy to adjust globally... And some huge disadvantages regarding hard coded string references etc .. up to you which one overrules in your opinion